# how to create a word2vec model with data extracted from wikipedia summary in python

Tags: python, wikipedia, gensim, word2vec

I would like to extract data from the wikipedia summary page of "machine learning" and then use that data to build a word2vec model with gensim library.

So, first I get the wiki summary of "machine learning" (Wikipedia API for Python):

```
sentences = wikipedia.summary("machine learning")
```

and then I create the model:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=2, size=50, window=4)
```

The problem is that, if I print the vocabulary keys, I get a list of characters rather than a list of words. The following is the code that I use to print the vocabulary keys:

```
print list(model.vocab.keys())
```

Where I am wrong?

Here I pasted the full code:

```
import wikipedia, gensim.models
sentences = wikipedia.summary("machine learning")
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=2, size=50, window=4)
print list(model.vocab.keys())
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing following two things:

1. Converting unicode into UTF-8
2. Use of *gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence* for making gensim object

Following is complete working python script:

```
# libraries
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence
import wikipedia

# word2vec model parameters
min_count = 2
size = 50
window = 4

# getting "machine learning" summary from wikipedia
summary = wikipedia.summary("machine learning")

# Changing unicode to UTF-8 and writing summary to a text file
text = summary.encode("UTF-8")
filewriter = open("machine_learning.txt", "w")
filewriter.write(text)
filewriter.close()

# reading machine_learning.txt file by using LineSentence
sentences = LineSentence("machine_learning.txt")

# making gensim model and training it on sentences
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count = min_count, size = size, window = window)

# printing model's vocablury
print(model.vocab.keys())

# printing vector for 'learning' word
print(model["learning"])
```

Hope it helps..!